# Is it safe to delete these python files from /usr/bin?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, homebrew, pyenv

[image]

I've installed python 2x and 3x with **Homebrew** at `/usr/local/Cellar/`, and again with **pydev** at `~/.pyenv` for both versions. Also installed with **.dmg** for both. I can't decide which is nicer to work on. Please advice me.

And I'd like to remove some. Which of these would be unnecessary and can be removed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

don't delete files on /usr/bin, if you want to remove some python, like python2: `brew uninstall python2`.

The `pyenv` is a very good tool. I'm use it betw on py2 or py3 very well.
And there is another good tool for python dev：`virtualenv`

Comment: Thanks, @zhiliang wang!